# How do I access class variable?

Tags: ruby

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def test
    @goodbay = TestClass.varible
  end
end

class TestClass
  @@varible = "var"
end
```

and i get error

```
undefined method 'varible' for TestClass:Class
```

on the line `@goodbay = TestClass.varible`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Ruby, reading and writing to `@instance` variables (and `@@class` variables) of an object must be done through a method on that object. For example:

```
class TestClass
  @@variable = "var"
  def self.variable
    # Return the value of this variable
    @@variable
  end
end

p TestClass.variable #=> "var"
```

Ruby has some built-in methods to create simple accessor methods for you. If you will use an instance variable on the class (instead of a class variable):

```
class TestClass
  @variable = "var"
  class << self
    attr_accessor :variable
  end
end
```

Ruby on Rails offers [a convenience method](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/mattr_accessor) specifically for class variables:

```
class TestClass
  mattr_accessor :variable
end
```

Comment: cattr_accessor is the better name, but it's just an alias to mattr_accessor (per the link I gave).

Comment: Also as a note this need not have an accessor method as `Object#instance_variable_get` will allow access to all instance variables (`@`) and `Object#class_variable_get` offers the same for class variables (`@@`) without the need for an explicit getter method e.g. `TestClass.instance_variable_get(:@variable)` or `TestClass.class_variable_get(:@@variable)`

Comment: Thanks, it's work! I was hoping to see more flexibility on the ruby. It turns out we use the getter instead of direct access to the variables, it will not be comfortable with a small pojo objects.

Comment: @engineersmnky, if you publish this as an answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: Re accessing instance/class variables (mainly from the console), for me it worked like `FooClass.class_variable_set(:@@foo, 'bar')` and `FooClass.class_variable_get(:@@foo)`, and for instances `foo_class.instance_variable_set(:@foo, 'baz')` and `foo_class.instance_variable_get(:@foo)`.  They accept either symbols `:@foo` or strings `'@foo'`.  (Thanks @engineersmnky for posting.)

Comment: shouldn't be breaking Open/Close Principle if you don't know what you are doing. I highly suggest you to use Instance var if you need mutations!

Answer (score 9):

here's another option:

```rb
class RubyList
  @@geek = "Matz"
  @@country = 'USA'
end
RubyList.class_variable_set(:@@geek, 'Matz rocks!')
puts RubyList.class_variable_get(:@@geek)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to access the class variable correctly. One of the ways is as follows:

```
class TestClass
  @@varible = "var"

  class << self
    def variable
      @@varible
    end
  end

 # above is the same as
 # def self.variable
 #   @@variable
 # end
end

TestClass.variable
#=> "var"
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but unfortunately, this has caused tighter error.

Comment: @VladislavAniskin this could not have caused error because it is correct (one of few) way to access class variable.

Comment: @VladislavAniskin how did you come up with `this has caused tighter error`? Did you even tried it?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the platform. I try, I saw the same thing/

Comment: @VladislavAniskin impossible, unless you're on windows :D This code is 101% working and correct, I assure you

Comment: I believe, but I is not the first oddity. with the operator of the regular expression = ~ have an error, too, that there is no such statement.

Comment: Under the windows? never bro!

Comment: OMG, why you blame Windows? Do you know how computer works at all? p RUBY_VERSION

Comment: @Nakilon 1) didn't know "OMG" is still used on the internet :) 2) It was almost a year ago. 3) It was an innocent joke, not more than that.

Comment: I wonder, why the downvote? I'd be glad to improve the answer.